# Bulk Upload to Vimeo with tagging, description, thumbnail

Tags: api, video, upload, vimeo, bulk

very new to uploading videos to Vimeo and trying to figure out if it is the right avenue.  I have a customer that is looking to upload about 1000 videos in HD quality after a specific event.

The would like to be able to just FTP the videos to me and then on my end I need to create a script/program/whatever to get the videos to Vimeo and provide tags, album designation, descriptions, etc.  And they want to be able to specify the thumbnail from the video.

My questions:

Is this possible?  It appears through the API that everything except specifying the thumbnail from the video is possible unless I am missing something.

Is there a better way?  Are there 3rd party apps that already do this that work well so I don't have to re-invent the wheel?

Thanks!

Comment: FTP upload is possible for Pro accounts http://vimeo.com/help/faq/uploading-to-vimeo/uploading-with-ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, everything except for specifying the thumbnail is currently available. In the near future (no time frame) Vimeo will support this through the new API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api).

I'm not aware of any third party code that already offers this functionality.

Comment: Thanks!  Being new to Vimeo I wanted to be sure I was understanding correctly.  Bummer, that API functionality is something everyone seems to want!